# Logic issue - sum of numbers

Tags: python

I need some help with the logic of a program.  What I am trying to do:

Write a program with a loop that asks the user to enter a series of positive numbers.  The 
user should enter a negative number to signal the end of the series.  After all the positive 
numbers have been entered, the program should display the sum.

```
keep_going = ' '
max = ()
total = 0.0

print('This program will add numbers together until a negative number is entered.')
print('It will then show the total of the numbers entered.')

while keep_going != (-):
    number = int(input('Enter a number: '))
    total = total + number

print('The total is', total)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: This `(-)` doesn't look like valid syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an infinite loop and test if the number just entered is *smaller than 0*:

```
total = 0

while True:
    number = int(input('Enter a number: '))
    if number < 0:
        break
    total = total + number
```

Only by testing the number just entered can you detect when a negative number has been entered.

Comment: Should you check the return value of `input()` before applying `int()`?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: You can use exception handling, but by the looks of it this is a beginner, learning to program. Tutorials often assume the user will just enter valid numbers and introduce exception handling later.

Comment: Yeah, but just to be clear the program will crash if I enter `'a'`

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: see [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23294659) for best practices.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I am having a day....

Answer (score 0):

You never change the value of `keep_going`, so your loop will never terminate.

Comment: You cannot even test against `(-)`; that's an operator in parentheses, and not legal syntax.

Comment: I figured that was the case too, but I don't know much Python.